How to use DrawContext Minecraft Fabric
I want to draw a big dot on the screen on a specific X,Y Coordinate
I calculated the coordinates, but I'm stuck drawing that on screen I saw examples online, but can't get it to work with my script.
I also learned that we now use DrawContext, I can't get it to work.
`package be.mpenson.fireballdetector;

import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.event.lifecycle.v1.ClientTickEvents;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.font.TextRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.DrawContext;
import net.minecraft.client.util.math.MatrixStack;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.DragonFireballEntity;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.FireballEntity;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.SmallFireballEntity;
import net.minecraft.particle.ParticleTypes;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.math.Box;
import net.minecraft.util.math.MathHelper;
import net.minecraft.util.math.Vec3d;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import net.fabricmc.api.EnvType;
import net.fabricmc.api.Environment;

import java.awt.*;


@Environment(EnvType.CLIENT)
public class FireballdetectorClient implements ModInitializer {
    public static final String MOD_ID = "fireball-detector";
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MOD_ID);



    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        int screenWidth = 1920;
        int screenHeight = 1080;
        LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(screenWidth));
        LOGGER.info("Mod loaded successfully");

        ClientTickEvents.END_CLIENT_TICK.register(client -> {
            MinecraftClient minecraftClient = MinecraftClient.getInstance();

            if (minecraftClient.player != null && minecraftClient.world != null) {
                Vec3d playerPos = minecraftClient.player.getPos();
                Box playerBoundingBox = minecraftClient.player.getBoundingBox().expand(8.0);

                for (Entity entity : minecraftClient.world.getEntities()) {
                    if (entity instanceof FireballEntity || entity instanceof SmallFireballEntity || entity instanceof DragonFireballEntity) {
                        Vec3d fireballPos = entity.getPos();
                        Vec3d fireballVelocity = entity.getVelocity();

                        boolean willCollide = false;
                        Vec3d currentPos = fireballPos;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
                            currentPos = currentPos.add(fireballVelocity);

                            minecraftClient.world.addParticle(ParticleTypes.FLAME, currentPos.x, currentPos.y, currentPos.z, 0, 0, 0);

                            if (playerBoundingBox.intersects(currentPos.x, currentPos.y, currentPos.z, currentPos.x, currentPos.y, currentPos.z)) {
                                willCollide = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (willCollide) {
                            minecraftClient.player.sendMessage(Text.literal("Warning: Incoming fireball!"), true);
                            
                            Vec3d directionToFireball = fireballPos.subtract(playerPos).normalize();
                            float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(directionToFireball.z, directionToFireball.x)) - 90;
                            float playerYaw = minecraftClient.player.getYaw();

                            float relativeYaw = MathHelper.wrapDegrees(angle - playerYaw);
                            float relativePitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(directionToFireball.y));
                            
                            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(relativeYaw));
                            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(relativePitch));
                            int x = (int) ((relativeYaw + 180) / 360.0 * screenWidth);
                            int y = (int) ((relativePitch + 90) / 180.0 * screenHeight);

                            DrawContext d = new DrawContext();
                            d.drawText("•", x, y, Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

`
gradle.properties
# Done to increase the memory available to gradle.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -Xms4G
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Fabric Properties
# check these on https://fabricmc.net/develop
minecraft_version=1.21.1
yarn_mappings=1.21.1+build.3
loader_version=0.16.3

# Mod Properties
mod_version=1.0.0
maven_group=be.mpenson.fireballdetector
archives_base_name=fireball-detector

# Dependencies
fabric_version=0.103.0+1.21.1

I also tried using AI but they fallback to the old system as they are capped at 2021/2023
